# Check attributes of input field in JS handler LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

Suppose there are 2 input fields in HTML file of LWC component.
One input field is required and other is not.
Both the input fields are calling same handler.

```
 <lightning-input key={param} name={param.name} type="text" label=""  **required="true"**
              onchange={handleInput}>
</lightning-input>

 <lightning-input key={param} name={param.name} type="text" label=""  
              onchange={handleInput}>
</lightning-input>
```

JS Code :

```
handleInput(event) {
 // Check whether input field has required attribute
}
```

Q. Can we check inside handler whether input field which invoked handler has "required attribute" ?
We can put custom attribute using data-id. Can we achieve without that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can access all the properties of the field through `event.target`:

```
handleInput(event) {
  console.log(event.target.required);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
It is working